# Venting time of a Pressurized tank

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to calculate venting time of a pressurized tank filled with saturated water at 800 PSIG.

The vent from the tank is a 2 inch line 12 ft long which goes into 6 inch line 10 ft long and then it goes into 8 inch line 150 ft long. These lines vent into a flash tank (Operating at 50 PSIG), which then is released into atmosphere.

My questions would be:

1. Velocity of water into tank?
2. Water pressure coming into the flash tank?

I have attached sample calculation regarding how I am approaching this problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I am using Bernoulli equations, Darcy Weisbach equation to balance pressure

Calculations that I am performing:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using SI?

Comment: In my calcs I am converting everything to SI for simplicity, I am in USA hence the PSIG unit

Comment: This question would be better suited to Physics stack exchange, since it does not deal with programming but with the calculations directly

Comment: I actually figured it out. Essentially the flow of liquid through first valve has to be assumed as choked flow.